# Having trouble getting a button to render in Python Crash Course

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm learning python using Python Crash Course, and I think I have the correct code and yet its not yielding the desirable effect. The code is supposed to be freezing the game and displaying a "play button", but no play button is appearing.

Here is the "Alieninvasion.py" file:

```
import sys
from time import sleep

import pygame

from settings import Settings
from game_stats import GameStats
from ship import Ship
from bullet import Bullet
from alien import Alien
from button import Button




class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
       pygame.init()
       self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.settings.screen_width = self.screen.get_rect().width
        self.settings.screen_height = self.screen.get_rect().height
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        # Create an instance to store game statistics.
        self.stats = GameStats(self)

        self.ship = Ship(self)
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.aliens = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self._create_fleet()

        # Make the Play button.
        self.play_button = Button(self, "Play")

        # Set the background color.
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        if self.stats.game_active:
            self._check_events()
            self.ship.update()
            self._update_bullets()
            self._update_aliens()
            self._update_screen()

    def _update_bullets(self):
        """Update position of bullets and get rid of old bullets."""
        # Update bullet positions
        self.bullets.update()

        # Get rid of bullets that have disappeared.
        for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
            if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
                self.bullets.remove(bullet)

        self._check_bullet_alien_collisions()

    def _check_bullet_alien_collisions(self):
        """Respond to bullet-alien collisions."""
        # Remove any bullets and aliens that have collided.
        collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(
            self.bullets, self.aliens, True, True)

        if not self.aliens:
            # Destroy existing bullets and create new fleet.
            self.bullets.empty()
            self._create_fleet()

    def _ship_hit(self):
        """Respond to the ship being hit by an alien."""
        if self.stats.ships_left > 0:
            # Decrement ships_left.
            self.stats.ships_left -=1

            # Get rid of any remaining aliens and bullets.
            self.aliens.empty()
         self.ship.center_ship()

            # Pause.
            sleep(0.5)
     else:
            self.stats.game_active = True

    def _create_fleet(self):
        """Create the fleet of aliens."""
        # Create an alien and find the number of aliens in a row.
        # Spacing between each alien is equal to one alien width.
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        available_space_x = self.settings.screen_width - (2 * alien_width)
        number_aliens_x = available_space_x // (2 * alien_width)

        # Determine the number of rows of aliens that fit on the screen.
        ship_height = self.ship.rect.height
        available_space_y = (self.settings.screen_height -
                         (3 * alien_height) - ship_height)
        number_rows = available_space_y // (2 * alien_height)


        # Create the full fleet of aliens.
        for row_number in range(number_rows):
            for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
                self._create_alien(alien_number, row_number)

    def _create_alien(self, alien_number, row_number):
        """Create an alien and place it in the row."""
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
        alien.rect.x = alien.x
        alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
        self.aliens.add(alien)


    def _check_events(self):
        """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
        # Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)

    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        """Respond to keypresses."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            self._fire_bullet()

    def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
        """Respond to key releases."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = False

    def _fire_bullet(self):
        """Create a new bullet and add it to the bullets group."""
        if len(self.bullets) < self.settings.bullets_allowed:
            new_bullet = Bullet(self)
            self.bullets.add(new_bullet)

    def _update_aliens(self):
        """
        Check if the fleet is at an edge,
        then update the positions of all aliens in the fleet.
        """
        self._check_fleet_edges()
        self.aliens.update()

        # Look for alien-ship collisions.
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self.ship, self.aliens):
            self._ship_hit()

        # Look for aliens hitting the bottom of the screen.
        self._check_aliens_bottom()

    def _update_screen(self):
        """Update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen."""
        # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loopp
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()
        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()
        self.aliens.draw(self.screen)

        # Draw the play button if the game is inactive.
        if not self.stats.game_active:
            self.play_button.draw_button()

        # Draw the play button if the game is inactive.
        if not self.stats.game_active:
            self.play_button.draw_button()

        pygame.display.flip()



    def _check_fleet_edges(self):
        """Respond appropriately if any aliens have reached an edge."""
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            if alien.check_edges():
                self._change_fleet_direction()
                break

    def _change_fleet_direction(self):
        """Drop the entire fleet and change the fleet's direction."""
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            alien.rect.y += self.settings.fleet_drop_speed
        self.settings.fleet_direction *= -1

    def _check_aliens_bottom(self):
        """Check if any aliens have reached the bottom of the screen."""
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            if alien.rect.bottom >= screen_rect.bottom:
                # Treat this the same as if the ship got hit.
                self._ship_hit()
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make a game instance, and run the game.
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

and here is the button and game stats codes:

gamestats.py

```
class GameStats:
    """Track statistics for Alien Invasion."""

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize statistics."""
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.reset_stats()
        # Start Alien Invasion in an inactive state.
        self.game_active = True

def reset_stats(self):
    """Initialize statistics that can change during the game."""
    self.ships_left = self.settings.ship_limit
```

and

button.py

```
import pygame.font

class Button:

    def __init__(self, ai_game, msg):
        """Initialize button attributes."""
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()

        # Set the dimensions and properties of the button.
        self.width, self.height = 200, 50
        self.button_color = (0, 255, 0)
        self.text_color = (255, 255, 255)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

        # Build the button's rect object and center it.
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        self.rect.center = self.screen_rect.center

        # The button message needs to be prepped only once.
        self._prep_msg(msg)


    def _prep_msg(self, msg):
        """Turn msg into a rendered image and center text on the button."""
        self.msg_image = self.font.render(msg, True, self.text_color,
        self.button_color)
        self.msg_image_rect = self.msg_image.get_rect()
        self.msg_image_rect.center = self.rect.center

    def draw_button(self):
        # Draw blank button and then draw message.
        self.screen.fill(self.button_color, self.rect)
        self.screen.blit(self.msg_image, self.msg_image_rect)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
self.game_active = True
```

this line in `game_stats` should be set to `False` to start the game...since it's set to `True`, this condition is never met in `alien_invasion update_screen`:

```
if not self.stats.game_active:
    self.play_button.draw_button()
```

Hope you already caught that, came across this looking for another issue with that book. Also, you have the above comment/line/line duplicated in your code...not that it makes any difference.